# Group Delimited Flat Data using Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I've got some delimited data that I need to get into a Flex tree view (or some other kind of control that can display a hierarchy.) The data looks like this:

```
item1,groupA,mainGroup,root
item2,groupA,mainGroup,root
groupA,mainGroup,root
groupB,mainGroup,root
item3,groupB,mainGroup,root
item4,groupB,mainGroup,root
mainGroup,root
groupC,mainGroup,root
groupD,someOtherGroup,root
root
```

My flex app is connected to a jboss server that could potentially remove the root element (if necessary), but it really can't build the tree structure (for a variety of reasons unrelated to this question.)

At any rate, that needs to translates to a tree like this (the actual order doesn't matter, just the hierarchy.):

```
++ root
|-+ mainGroup
| |-+ groupA
| |  - item1
| |  - item2
| |-+ groupB
| |  - item3
| |  - item4
| |-+ groupC
|-+ someOtherGroup
| |-+ groupD
```

I know how to group flat data using a grouping collection, as is described [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_08.html). But I haven't had any luck figuring out a way to get flex to actually read/interpret the delimited format (without preprocessing it and building the correct structure myself.)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I think pre-processing it is going to be the only way.  What I mean by that is having a method you write that creates the GroupingCollection appropriately based on an algorithm which is based on your initial data.

Comment: Yeah ... I'm thinking that as well ... if you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think pre-processing it is going to be the only way. What I mean by that is having a method you write that creates the GroupingCollection appropriately based on an algorithm which is based on your initial data.

The split method:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split()

GroupingCollection:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/GroupingCollection.html#grouping

Grouping:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/Grouping.html#fields

GroupingField:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/GroupingField.html

In looking through the docs they do have those groupingObjectFunction properties though for the life of me I can't understand what that's supposed to do.